# How to open existing C++ project with Eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse

I have two projects in C++ that I need to run and build both in Windows and Linux.
We are using Microsoft TFS for source control.

- For windows we are using Visual Studio.
- For Linux we are using Eclipse. (I don't have much experience with Eclipse)

I had managed to configure and build properly the projects in both platforms.

I checked in TFS the **.cproject** and **.project** from eclipse, so I can use it in another computer.

Now I am trying to get the projects in another Linux computer and I don't know how to do it.

I tried following [this instructions](http://agile.csc.ncsu.edu/SEMaterials/tutorials/import_export/), but I don't have my source code zipped.

Other places like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11620730/752842) suggest creating a new project.

Isn't there a way to open an existing project in Eclipse similar to Visual Studio?

Do I have to create a new project? If so, how can I keep the configurations I did to be able to build the project so other developer can use them?

Comment: _'I checked in TFS the .cproject and .project ...'_ That's usually not a good idea. Pathes stored there are specific for the current development machine!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ ok, so there is no way to save project configuration so it can be used later in another computer or by other developer?

Comment: Of course there is. Just don't use absolute paths in your configuration. Make them relative to some environment variable instead

Comment: @jasal my paths are relative, so is it ok that I check in the .project and .cproject?

Comment: @Dzyann I just updated the instructions. If all paths are relative (including the compiler settings, etc!) it should work on other machines as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

File > Import... > General > Existing projects into workspace

Don't select an archive file. Set the root directory to where your `.project` and `.cproject` files are located. Your project should show up in the list. Make sure you don't forget to check the checkbox in front of your project.

Committing eclipse project files to a version control system is perfectly fine as long as you don't use absolute paths in your project settings. Use environment variables to specify paths which differ between developer machines.

Comment: Oh, I tried doing that at first, but it wasn't working, I think maybe there was something wrong with my workspace. What does that do? Does it copy my existing .cproject and .project to the workspace? or do they remain in my folder so I can check-in any future changes?

Comment: The project files will be copied to the workspace only when you select that option in the import dialog.

Comment: @jasal, hi, thank you for the information. I imported as you said, than what? I tried Ctrl+B(build all) but it says "make: *** No rule to make target `...Src/main.c', neede by `.../User/main.o'. Stop. How do I make the Makefile or build them? By the way, I copied the project into my workspace during import.

Comment: Hard to say without exact knowledge of your project contents. Do you have a main.c in the project's source folder?