# How do I upgrade Cordova 2.9.0 to 3.6 in Android Developer Tools?

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

Recently I was sent a warning by Google to upgrade my app to use Cordova 3.5.1 because of a possible security vulnerability in previous versions. I see the latest version of Cordova is 3.6, so I might as well upgrade to that.

I am using Android Developer Tools, based on Eclipse, to build my Android app. All I want to do is replace Cordova 2.9.0 with version 3.6, then rebuild the app and upload it to the market.

I went through all this stuff a year ago, but I'm struggling to retrace my steps on how I set it up. The Eclipse interface is anything but intuitive and easy to use. It's [not even obvious how to open an existing project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11619790/184108). Also, it seems Cordova has changed such that it's not simply a matter of replacing the existing `.jar` file. Things have changed significantly since I was last dealing with this.

How do I upgrade Cordova to the latest version **in the context of using Google's Android Develpment Tools (ADT)**? Specifically, I want to make an existing ADT project use the new Cordova version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Updated answer:**

Several important things have changed since 2.9.0.  As a result, the structure of your Cordova 2.9.0 project is not compatible with Cordova 3+.

One of the most important changes is that in Cordova 3.0, all of the APIs were moved from the framework into plugins.  This means that for any Cordova APIs you use, in a 3.0+ project, you will need to add plugins to your project before those APIs will be available.  For example, in Cordova 2.9.0, the Cordova Camera APIs were built in to the Cordova framework, so you would be able to call [navigator.camera.getPicture(successCB, errorCB, options)](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.9.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#camera.getPicture) without adding any plugins to your project.  Starting in Cordova 3.0, you would need to add [the Cordova Camera plugin](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.camera) to your project in order to make that same call.

There is no way to upgrade from 2.9.0 to 3.6.0 only using Android Developer Tools.  There is more than one way to upgrade, but I recommend that you follow the steps laid out in the upgrade grade in the official documentation.  The upgrade guide only lists incremental steps, which might be confusing if you have not done any Cordova development since 2.9.0, so here's a 2.9.0 to 3.6.0 summary based on the incremental steps defined in the "Upgrading Android" guide from the official documentation.

There are several steps that you will need to complete.

1. Backup your original project in case something goes awry and you need to start over.  If you have cordova 2.9.0 installed, create a new blank project.  You can use this as a baseline to find what custom assets you've added by using a diff tool.  This might be helpful in step 4.
2. Install cordova 3.6.0 by following the instructions in [the official documentation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.6.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface).
3. Create a new cordova project, using your project's package name and application title:

`cordova create projectPath projectPackage projectName`

3. Change to the project directory and add the Android platform:

`cd projectPath
cordova platform add android`

4. Copy your custom project assets from your original project into your new project.
   a. the contents of assets/www excluding config.xml, cordova_plugins.js, cordova_plugins.json and cordova.js.
   b. the contents of res/drawable*
   c. depending on your project, there may be other native assets that you will need to copy - but be careful about overwriting files - in some cases you might need to copy your custom contents into the existing file in your new project instead of overwriting it.  When in doubt, compare the files side-by-side.
5. Install any "core" plugins that you need.  You'll need to identify which Cordova APIs your projects uses, then identify the plugin that provides them.  In most cases, you should be able to start by referring to the [Cordova 2.9.0 API Reference in the sidebar](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.9.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#camera.getPicture) to see which Cordova 2.9.0 object provided the API you use, then match it up with the corresponding plugin in the [Cordova 3.6.0 Plugin APIs list](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.6.0/cordova_plugins_pluginapis.md.html#Plugin%20APIs).  In some cases names have been changed but for the most part it should be straightforward to find the plugin you need.  For example, to install the camera plugin, you would run the following command in the root of your project (NOT in the android root at platforms/android, but in the top-lvel root):

`cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera`

6. Deal with custom plugins.  If you are using any custom plugins, you will need to update to a newer version that is compatible with Cordova 3.6.0.
7. Update your project to account for API changes.  Some of the APIs have changed quite a bit since 2.9.0 - this might require you to make code changes.

---

**Original answer:**
[Here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.6.0/guide_platforms_android_upgrade.md.html#Upgrading%20Android) is the official documentation that describes how to upgrade from 2.9.0 to the latest version.

Unfortunately, the directory structure has changed a couple times since 2.9.0, so you'll have to manually move some files around.

If you have trouble following the documented steps please comment and I will try to assist.

Comment: THank you for responding. I had already seen this page, but I'm afraid what is hindering me is that all this assumes a command line interface, but I am using the Google ADT Eclipse interface. Since I'm not using the command line, all the references to project directories or creating projects at the command line are lost on me. In my ADT interface, there is a `jar` file for Cordoba. Can't I just replace it with a newer `jar` file?

Comment: No, you can't just replace the jar file.  There are a couple reasons.  Probably the most important is that in 2.9.0 all of the core Cordova APIs were built-in to the framework.  In 3.0.0, this was changed so that all of the core Cordova APIs were moved into plugins - this means that you need to add the set of plugins to your project that corresponds to the set of APIs that you are using.  The instructions do not all assume you are using CLI - if you scroll down there are separate instructions for upgrading from 2.9.0 to CLI 3.0.0 or non-CLI 3.0.0.

Comment: Thank you for your continued help. I understand your explanation as to why I can not just replace the jar file. However, the instructions on the page you link to still just lose me. For example, under the instructions to upgrade from 2.9 to 3.0, non-CLI, the first line says "Create a new Apache Cordova Android project." There is no such option (as far as I can see) in my ADT interface. I'm missing something fundamental here. I don't know the context in which these instructions are taking place.

Comment: Cordova support is not built in to ADT.  You have to make a new Cordova project, then import it into Eclipse.  I understand you are averse to the command line tools, but honestly, the easiest way to create a new project is to install the command line tools, create the project and add the android platform.  But if you want to avoid that, download the latest Cordova, currently https://www.apache.org/dist/cordova/platforms/cordova-android-3.6.3.tgz.  Look in the framework directory - you should be able to use that as the starting point to "Create a new Apache Cordova Android project."

Comment: Thank for your continued help. I'm actually not adverse to using the command line, it's just that I am not at all clear on how Cordova and Eclipse relate, and I just want to make sure the instructions I get apply to the goals I have. I already have an existing project within Eclipse, and so far the CLI instructions I've seen for Cordova involve starting a new project in ways I don't grasp, so I'm unclear on how I take a Cordova project created at the command line and marry it to my existing ADT project.

Comment: Following your last comment, I've imported the Cordova framework from the zip file into ADT. Now... how do I get it to apply to my existing project?

Comment: Well, if you aren't averse to using the CLI, then I recommend you install it and use that to create a project instead of starting with the framework download.  Once you create the new project, you will copy parts of your old project into the newly created project, update the configuration to match your project's requirements, then add plugins that provide the features that you are using.  Some of this can be done in Eclipse, some of it will need to be done on the command line.  I don't have time this morning, but I'll try to update my answer with a detailed example later today.

Comment: Great answer, I can follow it properly to step 5. I've created a brand new project this way, and when I import it into Eclipse I get two 2 projects "HelloWorld" and "HelloWorld-CordovaLib". I check both and press ok. When I try to do Build all on the HelloWorld project, I get an error "The import org.apache.cordova cannot be resolved" in src HelloWorld in onCreate.

Comment: @BdR - I've seen this happen before.  Try doing the following.  Close Eclipse, Open Eclipse, Open your HelloWorld workspace, clean all projects.  If that doesn't work, try right-clicking on your project, Properties->Android, Remove the CordovaLib reference, click Apply, click Add, select HelloWorld-CordovaLib, click Apply.  Not sure if any of that will help, but when I get weird import problems those are the first things I try.  Edit: I think this happens when you use your project directory as the workspace directory.  Try using a separate workspace directory, then import both.

Comment: @Dave. I found the CLI to be a bit daunting at first, mainly the installing part, but this video tutorial on YouTube was a great help to me. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gRY2TxWg4-4